# SQL - triggers and misadventures

Tags: mysql, sql

```
if (exists (select * from sysobjects where xtype='tr' and name='trig'))
    drop trigger trig1


go
create trigger trig1 on participari
after insert,update,delete
as
begin
    if (exists (select * from deleted))
        rollback

    if (exists (select * from inserted,proiecte
where inserted.idpr = proiecte.idpr
and deadline<dela union 
select * from inserted,proiecte
where inserted.idpr = proiecte.idpr and inserted.panala>proiecte.deadline))
end
```

A trigger i created for one of my tables. Basically it involves 2 tables. One is "proiecte" (projects) and the other one "participari"(paticipations). The projects table has the project id, name of the project and the deadline. The participation has project id(foreign), name of the participee, from and to (the interval of time, 2 different collumns marking each). It gives me an error at the end,  a syntax error and i can't wrap my head around it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be missing any action for the second `if` clause.

```
IF(
  EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM ...
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM ...
  )
)
-- do what?
```

Comment: *facepalm. thanks alot man, it's the kind of errors that are elementary but frequently take you hours if somebody else doesn't acutally look over them. it solved my issue, thanks again :D